# jQuery not sending the header with POST request

Tags: jquery, django

I have multiple jquery scripts with headers and they all are sending  `X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest`but one of the similar scripts is not sending this header.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var form = $("#msg-form");
form.on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    $("#sent-message").text("sending...");
    $.ajax({
        url: form.attr('action'),
        type: form.attr('method'),
        data: { 
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{csrf_token}}',
                'sent-message': $("#sent-message").val()

        },

        success: function(response){
            ("#upd-change").html(response);
        },
        headers: {
                            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
                    }
    });
});
});
```

template:

```
<form id="msg-form"  method="post" action="/send_message/{{r_user.id}}/{{from_user.id}}">
 {% csrf_token %}

 <div class="form-group">
  <div id="msg-send">
    <input type="text" name="sent-message" class="form-control" placeholder="please type message and press Enter to send"></input>
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

When I press enter it does send a post request but with header not containing `X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest`

I have also tried to submit this form using a button but same results.
The problem is that because of this behavior is_ajax is set to false. I have tried it in firefox and IE but I think the problem is not the compatibility because other scripts are running fine.

Any workaround? I have looked around for solution but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

try with [`$.ajax.beforeSend`](http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/)

```
$.ajax({
    url: form.attr('action'),
    type: form.attr('method'),
    data: { 
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{csrf_token}}',
            'sent-message': $("#sent-message").val()

    },
    success: function(response){
        ("#upd-change").html(response);
    },
    beforeSend: function(xhr){
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest');
    }
});
```